# Nothing handled the event error in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I am trying to filter a JSON response by using 'filterProperty' in Emberjs. But I am getting this error, `Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'last'`

Here's my App.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate : function(controller) {
        this.render('MyApp', {
            controller : controller
        });
    },
    model : function() {
        return App.MyTemplateModel.find();
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    last : (function() {
        this.get('content').filterProperty('last_name', 'Solow');
    }).property('content.@each.type')
});

App.MyTemplateModel = Ember.Model.extend({
    id : Ember.attr(),
    last_name : Ember.attr(),
    first_name : Ember.attr(),
    suffix : Ember.attr(),
    expiration : Ember.attr()
});

App.SiteController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

});

App.MyTemplateModel.url = "http://ankur1.local/index.php/api/example/users/";
App.MyTemplateModel.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create();
var existing = App.MyTemplateModel.find();
App.MyTemplateModel.camelizeKeys = true;
```

Here's my HTML page,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="MyApp">

            {{#each item in content }}
            <tr><td>
            {{id}} <p> {{item.first_name}} {{item.expiration}}</p>
            </td></tr>
            {{/each}}

            <button {{action last}}>filter</button>

        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            <h1>Application Template</h1>
            {{outlet}}
        </script>

    </body>
```

What I might be doing wrong in my App.js or should I use any other property to filter the JSON response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the property last on your IndexController as `Computed Property`, but if you want to use the `{{action}}` helper, this is not allowed. It has be a plain function. This is why Ember does not find a suitable event anywhere and complains about it.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    // for initial filling of this property, will be overridden by last action
    filteredContent : Ember.computed.oneWay("content"), 
    last : function() {
        var filtered = this.get('content').filterProperty('last_name', 'Solow');
        this.set("filteredContent", filtered);
    }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="MyApp">

{{#each item in filteredContent }}
  <tr><td>
  {{id}} <p> {{item.first_name}} {{item.expiration}}</p>
  </td></tr>
{{/each}}

<button {{action last}}>filter</button>

</script>
```

So i did basically two things:

1. **I changed the computed property to a plain function.**
2. **The template is iterating over filteredContent instead of content.** (Note the initialization i had to do on your Controller.)

Sou the basic mechanism is to have an additional property on your Controller, which holds the filtered content. You have to expand on this, because your usecase is a bit more complex for sure. :-)